# Eclipse - How do I create a table in the comment section of class/method?

Tags: java, eclipse, html-table, comments

I want to use `<\tbody>`, `<\tr>` and `<\td>` to create a table in the comment section of a method :

```
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td>personId</td>
    <td>y</td>
    <td>identifiant</td>
    <td>C16</td>
    <td>String</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>lastName</td>
    <td>n</td>
    <td>nom</td>
    <td>C32</td>
    <td>String</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work as I don't see a table in the Java doc, just the following :

```
personId y identifiant C16 String lastName n nom C32 String
```

What should I do ? The `<\table>` tag is not proposed by Eclipse and if I use it it doens't change anything. If it matters, I am using eclipse Neon.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? Also to you actually have `<table>` nodes around your `<tbody>` declaration?

Comment: Needs to be in JavaDoc

Comment: You don't specify the `<table>` element.

Comment: @Mena It is like Eclipse doesn't see my tags. So I have "personId y identifiant C16 String" etc.

Comment: @davidxxx <table> is not proposed and if I use it doesn't change anything.

Comment: @Flyout what does "Eclipse doesn't see my tags" mean? Are you trying to visualize a javadoc? If so, is the comment prepended with `/**`? Otherwise I still don't understand what's wrong.

Comment: Yes I am trying to visualize the Java doc, hovering the name of the method. Yes the comment is a /** */

Comment: Try `Tables (<table>...</table>) must be nested within paragraph (<p></p>) tags.` from https://dev.liferay.com/de/participate/advanced-javadoc-guidelines

Comment: you may want to use `<table border="1">` to get rendering of table grid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should specify the `table` element before `tbody` to be conform to [the `table` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table) :

> Permitted content
>
> In this order:
>
> - an optional caption element,
> - zero or more colgroup elements,
> - an optional thead element,
> - either one of the following:
>
>   - zero or more tbody elements
>   - one or more tr elements
> - an optional tfoot element

Second, you don't need Eclipse wizard or tool to document your Javadoc with HTML tags.
Just write your HTML content in a javadoc comment :

```
/**
<table><tbody>
<tr>
    <td>personId</td>
    <td>y</td>
    <td>identifiant</td>
    <td>C16</td>
    <td>String</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>lastName</td>
    <td>n</td>
    <td>nom</td>
    <td>C32</td>
    <td>String</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
 */
public void foo(){
  ...
}
```

And it should display it in a tabular way in the javadoc view or generation:

> **void foo()**
>
> personId y identifiant C16 String
>
> lastName n nom C32 String

Comment: well now It works. I don't know what happened I must have misspelled a tag or Something (<\table> is needed). Thank you to everyone.

Comment: You are welcome. The issue is sometimes a simple character or something that the OP could not imagine. That's why providing a a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example matters.

Answer (score 7):

As an alternative variant use `<pre></pre>` tag to render [markdown tables](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables#)

```
/**
 * Description
 * <pre>
 | Key   |    Value    |
 |-------|-------------|
 | 1     | Value1      |
 | 2     | Value2      |
 *</pre>
 */
```

Generates:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use markdown style table.  It's more readable than HTML one for developers.

Example:

```
/**
 *  2 Device Connected possible states matrix
 *
|         | DIALING | ON_HOLD | RINGING | ON_CALL | IDLE |
|---------|---------|---------|---------|---------|------|
| DIALING |   --    | YES     | YES     | YES     | YES  |
| ON_HOLD |  YES    | YES     | YES     | YES     | YES  |
| RINGING |  YES    | YES     | YES     | YES     | YES  |
| ON_CALL |  YES    | YES     | YES     | --      | YES  |
| IDLE    |  YES    | YES     | YES     | YES     | YES  |
 */
```

You can generate a table in markdown from here

https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables#

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [tool](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/) and specify the output style is HTML.